# $PATH environment variable in Ansible provisioner for Vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, ansible

When working with Ansible as a provisioner for Vagrant, variables that I define in `/etc/environment` are not being picked up. I can't find the documentation that says how vagrant builds it's environment variables.

Which file should I modify so that updates to the `PATH` environment are picked up by the Ansible provisioner?

```
// In my foo role/task...

- name: check path
  command: msg="{{ print $PATH }}"
```

Results in

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

I want to modify my `$PATH` so that it is available both to the Ansible provisioner and the users when they log into my Vagrant box.

Relevant questions:

- [Ansible - accessing local environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422158/ansible-accessing-local-environment-variables)

**Current /etc/environment configuration:**

```
vagrant@localhost:~$ cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/bin/composer:/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

**Contents of `roles/ansible_dev`:**

```
- name: check path
  shell: echo $PATH
  register: PATH
- debug: var=PATH
# outputs /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

- name: update path
  shell: source /etc/environment;export PATH

# outputs the same, note my .composer directory still missing at the end
- name: check path AGAIN
  command: echo $PATH
  register: PATH2
- debug: var=PATH2
```

**Testing**

After `vagrant up` I am doing `vagrant provision --provision-with=ansible` for testing.

```
TASK: [ansible_dev | check path] ********************************************** 
changed: [localhost]

TASK: [ansible_dev | debug var=PATH] ****************************************** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "PATH": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": "echo $PATH", 
        "delta": "0:00:00.002239", 
        "end": "2014-10-15 03:04:34.604944", 
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": "echo $PATH", 
            "module_name": "shell"
        }, 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2014-10-15 03:04:34.602705", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stdout": "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
        ]
    }
}

TASK: [ansible_dev | update path] ********************************************* 
changed: [localhost]

TASK: [ansible_dev | check path AGAIN] **************************************** 
changed: [localhost]

TASK: [ansible_dev | debug var=PATH2] ***************************************** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "PATH2": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": [
            "echo", 
            "$PATH"
        ], 
        "delta": "0:00:00.003051", 
        "end": "2014-10-15 03:04:34.814571", 
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": "echo $PATH", 
            "module_name": "command"
        }, 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2014-10-15 03:04:34.811520", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stdout": "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what that has to do with .composer, but replace `{{print $path}}` with `{{ lookup('env', 'PATH') }}`. Generally, path is modified by adding `export PATH=..` to a .bashrc or similar.

Comment: You mean something like `- debug: msg={{ lookup('env', 'PATH') }}` ? In that case that would be printing the `PATH` of the host environment, not the virtual machine (tested it). I want binaries installed in the VM as part of provisioning to be available to other roles further down during the provisioning process. Those binaries (in this case composer, could be anything else) are **NOT** in your usual `PATH` location. Doing `vagrant ssh` picks up binaries in paths defined by `PATH` in `/etc/environment`, therefore I don't get why `vagrant provision` doesn't.

Comment: @tedder42 see[ansible-accessing-local-environment-variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422158/ansible-accessing-local-environment-variables) and [playbooks_lookups](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_lookups.html). "Note: 
Lookups occur on the local computer, not on the remote computer.
"

Comment: good point @amateur-barista. In that case, perhaps you can use `shell` to register the client environment variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I think using ansible to provision `/etc/environment` is fine and when the box is fully provisioned and you login via ssh, the changes you made there should be in effect in those login shell sessions fine. My guess is that ansible is only making one initial ssh connection, loading the shell environment based on the initial `/etc/environment` and assorted bash configuration files, thus giving you an initial `PATH`. Then your playbook changes `/etc/environment` but that doesn't automatically reload the current session. You may have luck with a command to just do `exec $SHELL` and then after that your playbook plays should have the new `PATH`. If that still doesn't work try `source /etc/environment;export PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Still no dice. I provided additional information in the question. My `/etc/environment` **is** populated at the moment, while the machine is up. I'm just re-provisioning for testing but maybe I need to "re-up", IDK. Maybe the way that I am trying to update the environment or source in `/etc/environment` is wrong?

Comment: I get the sense that even if `/etc/environment` was hardcoded - not even provisioned, just came like that with the box, it is not getting picked up. More importantly, what I am wondering is where in the Ansible documentation is reflected their methodology for building the initial environment variables. That's a separate, broader question, but it would definitely answer my question. Two birds in one shot (wishful thinking)!

Comment: Ansible itself doesn't set this up. It's part of the operating system as well as the login shell (usually bash or dash). Just sourcing the file is not sufficient. Then it becomes shell variables but you need to `export` them to convert them to environment variables which are passed on to child processes. If you just manually edit /etc/environment and ssh in and you don't see those values present in the environment than take a step back because this has nothing to do with Ansible and you have some missing piece at the shell/OS level.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant by "it's not getting picked up" is that "it's not getting picked up **by ansible**". When I ssh in I do see everything made available by /etc/environment!

Comment: So I found what was issue that I was having: I don't know why... **Vagrant is running the Ansible provisioner as root**: `root@localhost:# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`. That explains everything. Finding out why Ansible is running as root is a different question, though.

Answer (score 0):

For me this ansible task worked best:

```
- name: Export language
  command: /usr/sbin/update-locale LANG={{ locale }} LC_ALL={{ locale }} LANGUAGE={{ locale }}
```