# How to use environment variables in Ansible?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible

I have a docker-compose project that I would like to convert to Ansible.

Everything is working fine but I want to convert the command below from docker compose to Ansible.
I tried to pass (env, envfile command) and it is still not working correctly. This is the command in docker compose

```
  Environment:
 - NGINX_HOST=http://nginx:80
```

Is there any way to select and use environment variables in Ansible playbook?
What is the syntax of this command in Ansible ?

my playbook

```
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  tasks:

  - name: 3
    command: docker build --network host -t man /home/my/Documents/2/mysite/

  - name: php
    docker_container:
      name: 1-php
      image: php:fpm
      state: started
      volumes:
       - ./file:/var/www/html/x.com

  - name: nginx-vts-exporter
    docker_container:
      name: x-Exporter
      image: sophos/nginx-vts-exporter:latest
      state: started
      ports:
       - 9913:9913


  - name: prom
    docker_container:
      name: x-prometheus
      image: prom/prometheus:latest
      state: started
      ports:
       - 9090:9090
      volumes:
       - ./monitor/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      links:
       - x-Exporter

  - name: nginx
    docker_container:
      name: x-Nginx
      image: nginx:latest
      volumes:
        - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/x.conf:ro
        - ./file:/var/www/html/x.com
      ports:
        - 80:80
      links:
        - 1-php
        - x-Exporter
```

Comment: For the enviroment variables of target machine, use `{{{{ lookup('env', 'NGINX_HOST') }}}}`. For the ones of source, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422158/ansible-accessing-local-environment-variables

Comment: i need to use it with docker  ... tried to use the syntax in the answer and it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use variable from vars. You can use syntax like this "{{repo}}", also key for environment variables is env, not Environment.

```
- hosts: fix
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    repo: test
  tasks:
    - name: prom
      docker_container
        env:
          REPO: "{{repo}}"
          HOSTIP: "{{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}"
          NGINX_HOST: http://nginx:80
```

Comment: i have added my playbook so you can see what i mean .... the exporter is not reaching the nginx image for that i want to add the environment command , can you edit it so it can reach end ecport metrics ?

Comment: Yes, updated, into docker_container section, you can put "env" sub section and place there, your environment variables

Comment: you mean like ...................      vars:
        NGINX_HOST: http://nginx:80/   if not can you edit you'r post and put the code in it

Comment: You can not used vars and just put string NGINS_HOST: "host"