# How to get dnsdomainname value in ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, hostname

I need dnsdomainname value in ansible variable.

```
$echo $(dnsdomainname)
```

To build http_proxy value with Ansible playbook, i need dnsdomainname value in local variable.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible - accessing local environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422158/ansible-accessing-local-environment-variables)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great discussion on importing environment variables into your playbook.

[Ansible - accessing local environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422158/ansible-accessing-local-environment-variables)

This documentation is for setting the variables in your inventory file.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html

I hope that helps.

EDIT:
@sorin's answer above should solve your problem.

```
{{ ansible_env.dnsdomainname }}
```

You can also use the module 'shell' to execute any command you want on the remote host.

```
- host {{ hosts }}
  gather_facts: "yes"

tasks:
 - shell: 'echo $dnsdomainname'
   register: dnsdomainname

 - debug:
     var: dnsdomainname
```

Comment: It's not a local value. The dnsdomainname value is set in remote virtual machine by google.